# Express.JS: Two users logged in simultaneously - keeping a user cookie while another user logs in

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, cookies, express

I have an application built in Express that has two different user roles: **admin** and **regular**.

Whenever a person signs up, there are two users created internally, one with the admin role and another with the regular role. Both of them are created with the same email address, but each one of them has a different password.

Right now, when a regular user logs in, she can switch (log in) to the admin counterpart by just entering the admin password.

I would like to add a feature to let them **switch back to the regular user** by just pressing a button, but this would imply to store somehow the regular user session cookie on the client.

How can I achieve this without compromising the security of the app?

These are the possible ways I have tried without any luck:

- **Create two different keys** for the session cookie, one for each type of user, so collisions are avoided and both cookies can coexist on the client at the same time.
- **Change the session cookie permissions** so I can access it from the JavaScript client and deal with it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question: if the user logs in as an admin in the first place, would you also want them to be able to shift to a regular user with no login, or is that not a supported use case?

Question 2: are you just rolling your own authentication and user management, or do you have another library in the mix which may be relevant?

Thoughts: Without knowing how you lay out your sessions, as well as how you store your users, but thinking about the way I do (which is that I have a `user` attribute of `req.session`): you could have a server method - let's just call it `downgradeUser()`.
When invoked, it could simply change the session.user object to the regular user which shares the email address with the then-current admin user. Assuming you have a function getRegularUserByEmail which looks up your user based on an email address, bypassing any password check.

```
app.get('/downgradeuser', function downgradeUser(req,res) {

    req.session.user = getRegularUserByEmail(req.session.user.email);
    // render, redirect, send a 200-OK, etc, based on how you're calling it.

});
```

While you could secure access to this method or add a check inside it to verify that the original session.user has the admin role, my quick thought is that you might not really need to, since if called by a regular user, the result would be resetting the `session.user` to the same thing it was, although you'd probably want to do the check to avoid the needless overhead of reloading the user as well as because you might consider an unexpected case for which you'd want a warning.

Let me know if I am missing something or if this isn't suitable for some reason.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Barry, thanks for the answer. I'm actually using Passport. I think your idea is the way to go, so I would need to set up another Passport LocalStrategy to handle this downgrading right?

Comment: I am not a Passport user (when I looked at it I didn't see a compelling need for me), so don't take my word for anything past this point. However, from my understanding of the doc I think you'd need to create a new Strategy (maybe using the passport-local code as a base, because you would need to trap the authenticate method since it would give you access to session. This could be a misunderstanding on my part though.